# Groovy split results

Tags: groovy

Script:

```
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import groovy.xml.XmlUtil;
    import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder;
    import groovy.xml.*;
    
    def Message processData(Message message) {
    
         // get body
        def body = message.getBody(java.io.Reader);
        
        // parse xml body
        def result = new XmlSlurper().parse(body);
    
        def message1 = result.Message1;
        def message2 = result.Message2;
    
    def one = message1.EmployeeDataReplicationConfirmation.EmployeeDataReplicationConfirmation.collect { it.personId.text() }
    def two = message2.queryCompoundEmployeeResponse.CompoundEmployee.collect { it.person.person_id.text() }
    def intersect = one.intersect(two)
    def userid1 = ((one - intersect) + (two - intersect))
    println((one - intersect) + (two - intersect))
    return message;
```

Output:

```
Console Output
Running...
[6107, 10140, 11774]
```

In the text 1 and text2 fields are different ids. This command will give me IDs that are the same in both.
But he gives them to me like this:[6107, 10140, 11774]
But i need it in XML.. like ..
I need this

```
<Person>
    <User>
    <userid>6107</userid>
    </User>
    <User>
    <userid>10140</userid>
    </User>
    <User>
    <userid>11774</userid>
    </User>
```

how can i do it ? Thanks :)

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: It didn't fail .. I just need to get it into the XML output

Comment: Have you looked at https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_creating_xml

Comment: Yes, but i need split ID's. I get this -<Person>
<User>
<userid>[6107, 10140, 11774]</userid>
</User>

Comment: Then please add your actual failing code.

Comment: I modified it .. Unfortunately I can't add input, it's too big code.. But it is a list of ID's

Comment: Please tag the question accordingly.  Most likely someone familiar with the SAP environment you are using there will be able to give way better help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MarkupBuilder` class to create your XML, imagine you already have your data ready, then the only thing you need to do is:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def userIds = [6107, 10140, 11774]

def xml = new StringWriter()
def builder = new MarkupBuilder(xml)

builder.people() {
   userIds.each { id ->
     user() {
      userId(id)
     }
  }
}

println xml
```

This will be the output

```xml
<people>
  <user>
    <userId>6107</userId>
  </user>
  <user>
    <userId>10140</userId>
  </user>
  <user>
    <userId>11774</userId>
  </user>
</people>
```

For more examples of working with XML, you can see my gist [Working with xml](https://gist.github.com/Joxebus/6790c71e61695918d7ad224a5cc4c0e7)